# Multi gene across multi sample correlation using R

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

I am following the recommendations of using rcorr [plain correlation matrix](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/240657_5157ff98e8204c358b2118fa69162e18.html#plain-correlation-matrix) using mtcars dataset using R. I would like to find the correlation for column; mpg to cyl, mpg to disp, mpg to hp and similarly for all other columns (multi sampling) for each of the cars listed as rownames. I understand it would create a large matrix of dataset but in my results for each of the correlation, I would like to know the rowname. My current code looks like this -

```
require(ggpubr)
require(tidyverse)
require(Hmisc)
require(corrplot)
data(mtcars)

flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat, pmat) {
  ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
  data.frame(
    row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
    column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
    cor  =(cormat)[ut],
    p = pmat[ut]
  )
}
tt <- mtcars

head(tt)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

dm = data.matrix(tt)
cc = rcorr(dm, type="pearson")
rcc = flattenCorrMatrix(cc$r, cc$P)
rc = data.frame(rcc)
head(rc)
```

The result is

```
head(rc)
   row column     cor                 p
   mpg    cyl -0.8522 0.000000000611269
   mpg   disp -0.8476 0.000000000938033
   cyl   disp  0.9020 0.000000000001803
   mpg     hp -0.7762 0.000000178783525
   cyl     hp  0.8324 0.000000003477861
  disp     hp  0.7909 0.000000071426787
```

However I would like to know what car to which a correlation occurred i.e. add a column to the above data frame "car model". In this case, the car model is the rowname from mtcars(above - tt).

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking isn't actually possible. That is because, each correlation listed above consist of data for multiple cars. For example, let's look at the first row:

```
   row column     cor                 p
   mpg    cyl -0.8522 0.000000000611269
```

This is a correlation between all values in the `mpg` column in your dataset and all values in the `cyl` column. so each row of your results is actually considering *all cars* in the `mtcars` dataset.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks